# Regex, Negative Lookback, Prevent Match

Tags: python, regex, assertion

I'm having some trouble working the logic of regular expressions in Python. I would like to write a regular expression that **doesn't** return a match if the string ends in a substring. Ultimately I'm trying to exclude any links to binary files that I find in the `href` attribute of `<a>` tags. (This is being implemented in Scrapy)

My issue is that if my regular expression is `[^ \t\n\r\f\v]+[\/]?(?<!.pdf)` and it finds a link to `someDocument.pdf` it returns `someDocument.pd`

How can I prevent from returning any match at all if it discovers that string?

Comment: "If the string ends in a substring": isn't this *always* true? All parts of the string are substrings, including the "end".

Comment: @Asad I think he means "if a string ends in a certain substring"

Comment: @AdamSmith Ah, I see, thanks. @OP So, just to clarify, are you looking for strings that don't end in `.pdf`? If so, you could just negate the result of testing a string for `^.*\.pdf$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using from scrapy, then you may need to add a `$` at the end of your regex:

```
[^ \t\n\r\f\v]+[\/]?(?<!\.pdf)$
```

If there is any way to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) from your project, then try it:

```
htmls = '''<a href="adssad/asdasd/asd.pdf">M</a> <a href='asdasdasdas/asdasd/asdasd.doc'></a>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls)
for link in soup.findAll("a", {"href":re.compile("(?<!\.pdf)$")}):
    print link['href']
```